# How can I import the kryonet library without "compile: " from gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I try to add the kryonet library with jar file, but I don't know how it must be added correctly in android-studio, libgdx project.
https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet

Comment: `without “compile: ” from gradle?` why?

Comment: Even with a JAR, there is still a `compile` line...

Comment: because the server uses diferent version of kryonet and I have just the same jar and because compile gradle doesn't work anyway, just for Desktop version but there are problems with different version of kryonet.

Comment: Please show your Gradle file and explain the exception that occurs when it doesn't work when you compile it

Comment: This comment on Github supposedly had a working Gradle configuration.  https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/pull/111#issuecomment-198682109

Comment: thanks @cricket_007 finally the gradle configuration worked, but when I run Desktop version appears an error 'Incorrect number of bytes (1 remaining) used to deserialize object: null'  caused by different version of kryonet because when I add jar (that works only for Desktop version) it works fine but in Android version appears error NoClassDefFoundError, and I need to add library locally.

Comment: Gradle will download a JAR file itself and it is local. The dependencies are not downloaded everytime you run the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `compile files('path/to/library.jar')` in dependencies in each module and all worked.

Comment: You really just need this line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`. No need to compile individual JAR files